# Cleaning Chromium based browser (Citrio)

Tags: finder, google-chrome, chrome-extensions

I'm currently trying to "clean" the Citrio browser of the extensions that are visible (maybe more that are hidden, but I'll investgate later).

These extensions cannot be deleted by simply clicking on the trashcan icon that is normally beside the extension. So I opted to delete the extension's files manually. I've gone as far as going into the Preference file and deleting any code related to the extension's ID.

I restart Citrio, and I get remnants of FILE_NOT_FOUND extensions across the Citrio browser.

In the picture below there is no trash can icon, and with no image or data files to go on, all that's left is to remove the last empty shell of the extension's entry in the chrome://extensions

[image]

If anyone can provide a way to remove the entry, thanks in advance!

Source followed for removing code in the Preferences file.
http://www.kuijjer.com/post/1367862444/how-to-remove-a-google-chrome-extension-on-mac-os

Comment: Also sidenote this isn't a major task, just something to do - Seeing if this browser can be handy. So if nothing can be done, no worries!

Answer (score 1):

Install the extensions: [Extensions Manager (aka Switcher)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/extensions-manager-aka-sw/lpleipinonnoibneeejgjnoeekmbopbc?hl=tr)

Removes one-click plug-ins :)

Comment: not suitable to this question since it only disables the extensions, and the extensions in question are already removed, the shell of the extensions only remain. As already said in the post.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaking, you can delete those extensions by clicking on the Details and there should be a Delete button.

Comment: -looks at picture- Do I see a trashcan? nahhh

Answer (score -2):

Sorry, for this late answer, but this will solve your Problem:

You need to navigate to %AppData%\Local\CatalinaGroup\Citrio\Application\50.0.2661.271\Extensions
modify "external_extensions.json" and delete every crx-File, except of those you want to keep. :D

[image: Proof]

Comment: That looks like a Windows path and so not useful for an Apple site

Comment: Also, I have already specified that I have deleted the extension's files in the question. All that's left is to remove that empty shell that says FILE_NOT_FOUND.